# Removing time, date and any icons from windows 8 lock screen

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

I'm trying to remove the date and wifi icon (all icons) from my windows 8 lock screen.
There are lots of posts about how to remove the time (that I have done) but before I accidently remove system 32, has anyone found a way to do this? I can't find anything :P

[How to remove the clock](http://dottech.org/99287/windows-8-how-to-customize-the-clock-on-lock-screen/)